# ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Reference to a local (non-exported) symbol

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have applied [IziToast](http://izitoast.marcelodolce.com/) in my project Angular2 project the code is :

```
import { OpaqueToken } from '@angular/core';

export let TOASTR_TOKEN = new OpaqueToken('iziToast')
```

iziToast.service.ts

```
export interface IziToast {
    success( message : messageJSON) : void ;
    info(message : messageJSON) : void ;
    warning(message : messageJSON) : void ;
    error(message : messageJSON) : void;
}
export interface messageJSON {
    title : string,
    message : string,
    position : string,
    color ?: string,
    layout ?: number
}
```

And my module looks like :
shared.module.ts

```
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { TranslateModule } from 'ng2-translate/ng2-translate';
import { ToasterModule } from 'angular2-toaster/angular2-toaster';

import { AccordionModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/accordion';
import { AlertModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/alert';
import { ButtonsModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/buttons';
import { CarouselModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/carousel';
import { CollapseModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/collapse';
import { DropdownModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/dropdown';
import { ModalModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/modal';
import { PaginationModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/pagination';
import { ProgressbarModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/progressbar';
import { RatingModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/rating';
import { TabsModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/tabs';
import { TimepickerModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/timepicker';
import { TooltipModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/tooltip';
import { TypeaheadModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/typeahead';
/*
    The presence of moment.js in DatepickerModule breaks lazyload. See:
        https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2496
        https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap/issues/1187
*/
// import { DatepickerModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/datepicker';

import { FlotDirective } from './directives/flot/flot.directive';
import { SparklineDirective } from './directives/sparkline/sparkline.directive';
import { EasypiechartDirective } from './directives/easypiechart/easypiechart.directive';
import { ColorsService } from './colors/colors.service';
import { CheckallDirective } from './directives/checkall/checkall.directive';
import { VectormapDirective } from './directives/vectormap/vectormap.directive';
import { NowDirective } from './directives/now/now.directive';
import { ScrollableDirective } from './directives/scrollable/scrollable.directive';
import { JqcloudDirective } from './directives/jqcloud/jqcloud.directive';
import { IziToast } from "./izitoastr.service";
import { TOASTR_TOKEN } from "./toastr-token.service";
import {ToastrMessageService} from "./toastr-message.service";

declare let iziToast: IziToast

// https://angular.io/styleguide#!#04-10
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        TranslateModule,
        AccordionModule.forRoot(),
        AlertModule.forRoot(),
        ButtonsModule.forRoot(),
        CarouselModule.forRoot(),
        CollapseModule.forRoot(),
        //.forRoot() DatepickerModule,
        DropdownModule.forRoot(),
        ModalModule.forRoot(),
        PaginationModule.forRoot(),
        ProgressbarModule.forRoot(),
        RatingModule.forRoot(),
        TabsModule.forRoot(),
        TimepickerModule.forRoot(),
        TooltipModule.forRoot(),
        TypeaheadModule.forRoot(),
        ToasterModule
    ],
    providers: [
        ColorsService,
        { provide : TOASTR_TOKEN, useValue : iziToast },
        ToastrMessageService
    ],
    declarations: [
        FlotDirective,
        SparklineDirective,
        EasypiechartDirective,
        CheckallDirective,
        VectormapDirective,
        NowDirective,
        ScrollableDirective,
        JqcloudDirective
    ],
    exports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        TranslateModule,
        RouterModule,
        AccordionModule,
        AlertModule,
        ButtonsModule,
        CarouselModule,
        CollapseModule,
        // DatepickerModule,
        DropdownModule,
        ModalModule,
        PaginationModule,
        ProgressbarModule,
        RatingModule,
        TabsModule,
        TimepickerModule,
        TooltipModule,
        TypeaheadModule,
        ToasterModule,
        FlotDirective,
        SparklineDirective,
        EasypiechartDirective,
        CheckallDirective,
        VectormapDirective,
        NowDirective,
        ScrollableDirective,
        JqcloudDirective
    ]
})

// https://github.com/ocombe/ng2-translate/issues/209
export class SharedModule {
    static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
            ngModule: SharedModule
        };
    }
}
```

I have imported in my constructor like :

```
@Inject(TOASTR_TOKEN) private toast : IziToast,
```

At beginning when I run `ng serve` it give me this error

```
ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Reference to a local (non-exported) symbol 'iziToast'. Consider exporting the symbol (position 42:5 in the original .ts file), resolving symbol SharedModule in /Users/Razmjo/workstation/nodejs/jobsaf/admin-panel/src/app/shared/shared.module.ts
```

When I change some code, and it recompile and the error disappear. It only give at beginning.

Thanks

**Edit**

My angular cli version is :

```
$ ng --version

Your global Angular CLI version (1.0.0) is greater than your local
version (1.0.0-rc.1). The local Angular CLI version is used.

To disable this warning use "ng set --global warnings.versionMismatch=false".
    _                      _                 ____ _     ___
   / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
  / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
 / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
/_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
               |___/
@angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.1
node: 7.4.0
os: darwin x64
@angular/common: 2.4.10
@angular/compiler: 2.4.10
@angular/core: 2.4.10
@angular/forms: 2.4.10
@angular/http: 2.4.10
@angular/platform-browser: 2.4.10
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 2.4.10
@angular/router: 3.4.10
@angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.1
@angular/compiler-cli: 2.4.10
NETLINKS-Nimat:admin-panel Razmjo$
```

Console log screen shot :

[image: Screen shot]

It gives error at first time, but when I change the code and recompile then the error is gone

**Edit2**

angular-cli.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "admin-panel"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "app/core/preloader/preloader.scss",
        "styles.scss"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
        "app/core/preloader/preloader.ts",
        "../node_modules/flot/jquery.flot.js",
        "../node_modules/jquery.flot.tooltip/js/jquery.flot.tooltip.js",
        "../node_modules/flot/jquery.flot.resize.js",
        "../node_modules/flot/jquery.flot.pie.js",
        "../node_modules/flot/jquery.flot.time.js",
        "../node_modules/flot/jquery.flot.categories.js",
        "../node_modules/jquery.flot.spline/jquery.flot.spline.js",
        "../node_modules/jquery-sparkline/jquery.sparkline.js",
        "../node_modules/easy-pie-chart/dist/easypiechart.js",
        "../node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.js",
        "../node_modules/jqcloud2/dist/jqcloud.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/js/modal.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/js/dropdown.js",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/js/tooltip.js",
        "../node_modules/summernote/dist/summernote.js",
        "../node_modules/moment/min/moment-with-locales.min.js",
        "../node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.js",
        "../node_modules/moment/moment.js",
        "./modernizr.js",
        "../node_modules/ika.jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js",
        "../node_modules/ika.jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js",
        "../node_modules/ika.jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-us-mill-en.js",
        "../node_modules/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.js",
        "../node_modules/codemirror/lib/codemirror.js",
        "../node_modules/codemirror/mode/javascript/javascript.js",
        "../node_modules/codemirror/mode/xml/xml.js",
        "../node_modules/codemirror/mode/htmlmixed/htmlmixed.js",
        "../node_modules/codemirror/mode/css/css.js",
        "../node_modules/jsonpath-plus/lib/jsonpath.js",
        "assets/lib/primus/primus.js",
        "../node_modules/izitoast/dist/js/iziToast.js"
      ],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "source": "environments/environment.ts",
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "scss",
    "prefixInterfaces": false,
    "inline": {
      "style": false,
      "template": false
    },
    "spec": {
      "class": false,
      "component": true,
      "directive": true,
      "module": false,
      "pipe": true,
      "service": true
    }
  }
}
```

style.css :

```
@import '../node_modules/izitoast/dist/css/iziToast.css';
```

Comment: `declare let iziToast: IziToast` What is this?

Comment: It is a global object

Comment: Its declaration

Comment: yes, it is,....

Comment: Angular expects value not declaration

Comment: aside from your question about the error. it seems like you are trying to build `iziToast` as an angular service. The whole thing is about 800 lines [link to iziToast.js](https://github.com/dolce/iziToast/blob/master/dist/js/iziToast.js) and youd be much better off converting it to a typescript service and sharing that on github for extra points ;)
if you dont want to do that, why not create a service that'll just abstract and call the `ziToast` api instead of having to do all that hacking.

Comment: actually, nvmd, they already have an ng2 module available here: https://github.com/plauzul/ng2-izitoast

Answer (score 0):

the problem is, you need export this thing, and initialize it.

```
export let iziToast: IziToast = {...};
```

Comment: could you capture your console tab?

Comment: what's about the shared.module.ts

Answer (score 0):

IziToast is already available for angular 2 as `ng2-izitoast`. Please use: https://github.com/plauzul/ng2-izitoast

Comment: They have created component which I dont want it. beside its only return show message. It is not useful for me

Comment: Please update your question with that info. Also, see my other comment on the question.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit late to the party but I encountered this problem today so figured I would post my solution here for prosperity sake.

I had a very similar situation to the op except I am using Angular 7 and creating a library, my module code was:

```
declare var AzureStorage: IAzureStorage;

export function azureBlobStorageFactory(): IBlobStorage {
  return AzureStorage.Blob;
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ]
})
export class AzureStorageModule {

  public static forRoot(options?: AzureStorageOptions): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: AzureStorageModule,
      providers: [
        {
          provide: AzureStorageOptionsToken,
          useValue: {
            ...options
          }
        },
        {
          provide: BLOB_STORAGE_TOKEN,
          useFactory: azureBlobStorageFactory
        }
      ]
    };
  }

}
```

And I was getting the same build error when running `ng build --project=<project_name>`

```
ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Reference to a local (non-exported) symbol 'AzureStorage'. Consider exporting the symbol
```

It turned out that all I needed to do to resolve the build error was to move the declaration and factory function out to a separate file and import them accordingly in the module. So my revised code looked like this:

In types.ts

```
declare var AzureStorage: IAzureStorage;

export function azureBlobStorageFactory(): IBlobStorage {
  return AzureStorage.Blob;
}
```

And my module now looked like

```
import { azureBlobStorageFactory } from './types';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ]
})
export class AzureStorageModule {

  public static forRoot(options?: AzureStorageOptions): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: AzureStorageModule,
      providers: [
        {
          provide: AzureStorageOptionsToken,
          useValue: {
            ...options
          }
        },
        {
          provide: BLOB_STORAGE_TOKEN,
          useFactory: azureBlobStorageFactory
        }
      ]
    };
  }

}
```